# object SequelizeInstance after a forEach loop

Tags: database, node.js, orm, sequelize.js, lodash

I'm working with Sequelize and a lodash template in a server side (NodeJS) to generate invoices. after each pass of the loop, I have a [object SequelizeInstance] that appears just above my html table.

```
compiled = _.template("
      <div class='row' style='padding: 20px 0px 0px 0px;'>
        <div class='col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12'>
          <div class='table-responsive'>
            <table border='1' style='width: 100%;'>
              <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th>Réf Produit.</th>
                  <th>Désignation</th>
                  <th>Quantité</th>
                  <th>Prix Unitaire</th>
                  <th>Sous Total</th>
                </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
              <% datas = []%>
              <% _.forEach(order.OrderedProducts, function(value, key) {%>
                <%- datas[key] = value %>
                <tr>
                  <td style='padding: 0px 0px 0px 4px;'><%- datas[key].Product.id %></td>
                  <td style='padding: 0px 0px 0px 4px;'><%- datas[key].Product.name %></td>
                  <td style='padding: 0px 0px 0px 4px;'><%- datas[key].quantity %></td>
                  <td style='padding: 0px 0px 0px 4px;'><%- datas[key].Product.price %> €</td>
                  <td style='padding: 0px 0px 0px 4px;'><%- datas[key].Product.price * datas[key].quantity %> €</td>
                <% }); %>
                </tr>
              </tbody>
            </table>
          </div>
          <hr>
          <div class='row'>
            <div style='float: right;' class='col-md-3'>
              <div class='ttl-amts'>
                <h5>  Sous Total : <%= Math.round((order.total_cmd - ((order.total_cmd * 20) / 100)) * 100) / 100 %> €</h5>
              </div>
              <hr>
                <div class='ttl-amts'>
                  <h5>  TVA : 20%</h5>
                </div>
              <hr>
                <div style='padding: 0px 0px 20px 0px;' class='ttl-amts'>
                  <h4><strong>Montant Total : <%= order.total_cmd %> €</strong></h4>
                </div>
            </div>
          </div>
```

Can you help me to resolve this please ? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think you should change this line:

```
<%- datas[key] = value %>
```

to:

```
<% datas[key] = value %>
```

With the extra dash in there you are telling it to echo the value in datas[key], which translates to [object SequelizeInstance].

I would also like to point out that anywhere inside that forEach loop, you can replace datas[key] with value, and then just get rid of that line I mentioned altogether.